# Error occur when creating database connection?

Tags: java, jdbc

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at iir.connection.main(connection.java:35)
```

Nov 29, 2014 5:03:01 PM iir.connection main

SEVERE: null

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/bala

```
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)

at iir.connection.main(connection.java:40)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at iir.connection.main(connection.java:44)
```

Comment: did you check your driver jar is in your classpath?

Comment: If it is eclipse did you add the jar file (as external jar) in Java Build Path -> Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Since you had not shared the code, it is difficult to understand your requirement. Still, I am sharing some sample code which may help you to troubleshoot:

Database Used: Derby

To install and configure the database please refer the link: https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure

To Define the Properties file: `Database.properties`

```
url=jdbc:derby:myDerbyDB
driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

This will help you to modify the code with ease if database needs to be modified.

To test the connection with the database: `Connect.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Connect 
{
    public static Connection con;
    static String url,driver;

    public static void connectMe() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("database");
        driver=resource.getString("driver");
        url=resource.getString("url");
        Class.forName(driver);

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        if(con!=null)
            System.out.println("Connection Established!");
    }
}
```

To Create a table: `TableCreation.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TableCreation 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connect.connectMe();
        Statement st = Connect.con.createStatement();
        String query = "CREATE TABLE myJavaTable  (ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY, DATA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL) ";
        boolean val = st.execute(query);
        if (val == false) {
        System.out.println("Creation Successfull!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Creation not successfull!");
        }
        Connect.con.close();
     }

}
```

To Insert Data into the Table: `PreparedStatementInsert.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.*;

public class PreparedStatementInsert 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException
    {
        Connect.connectMe();
        String query;
        Statement st = Connect.con.createStatement();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        query="Insert into myJavaTable(DATA) Values(?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = Connect.con.prepareStatement(query);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of records to be inserted: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Data: ");
            ps.setString(1, in.readLine());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("One record inserted!");
        }
        TableRetrieve.main(args);
        Connect.con.close();
    }

}
```

To display the contents of the table: `TableRetrieve.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TableRetrieve 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connect.connectMe();
        Statement st = Connect.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = st.executeQuery("Select * from myJavaTable");

        while(rSet.next())
        {
            System.out.print("ID: "+rSet.getString(1));
            System.out.println("\tName: "+rSet.getString(2));
        }
        Connect.con.close();
    }

}
```

To update the contents of the table: `TableUpdate.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TableUpdate 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException
    {
        Connect.connectMe();
        String query;
        boolean flag = false;
        Statement st = Connect.con.createStatement();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the ID of the record to be updated");
        int userID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        query = "Select * from myJavaTable";
        ResultSet rSet = st.executeQuery(query);

        while(rSet.next())
        {
            int id = rSet.getInt("ID");
            if(userID==id)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the new data: ");
                String str = in.readLine();
                query="Update myJavaTable set Data='"+str+"' where ID="+id;
                int exe = st.executeUpdate(query);
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag==true)
            System.out.println("Updation successfull!");
        else
            System.out.println("Record not found!");

        System.out.println("Table after updation is as follows:");
        TableRetrieve.main(args);
        Connect.con.close();
    }

}
```

To delete the table created: `TableDrop.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.test.Derby;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TableDrop
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connect.connectMe();
        Statement st = Connect.con.createStatement();
        String query = "Drop table myJavaTable";
        boolean val = st.execute(query);
        if(val==false) {
        System.out.println("Table Dropped!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Table cannot be dropped!");
        }
        Connect.con.close();
    }

}
```

Hope these can help you. If you require more info, please comment on the answer. Please update my answer if you can contribute to this so that it may be more useful to others.